# Pi zero as bluetooth keyboard?

Tags: bluetooth, hid, bluez

I am attempting to use a Pi as a bluetooth keyboard.  There are several guides I have found for this, such as this on from [impythonist](https://impythonist.wordpress.com/2014/02/01/emulate-a-bluetooth-keyboard-with-the-raspberry-pi/).

However, they seem to be outdated, and so far as I can tell depend on bluez 4.x.

It does not matter to me if I have to install an older Raspbian or even a different OS altogether so long as it will boot on a Pi zero. Any ideas?

Comment: do you mean to have the raspberry pi connect to a device via bluetooth and act as a bluetooth keyboard for that device or connect the raspberry pi to a device as a keyboard and connect to the raspberry pi via bluetooth the former I have not accomplished the latter I have and can tell you how I did

Comment: Oops, that did not seem to work, trying a new comment...

Comment: @Binvention Not sure I understood the distinction between "have the raspberry pi connect to a device via bluetooth and act as a bluetooth keyboard for that device" and "connect the raspberry pi to a device as a keyboard and connect to the raspberry pi via bluetooth", however, I am all ears as to your solution.

Comment: So like say you want a wireless keyboard for a computer are you wanting to connect the raspberry pi to the computer via USB then connect to the raspberry pi via Bluetooth or connect to the computer via Bluetooth and connect to the raspberry pi by some other means

Comment: @Binvention I am wanting to connect the Pi to the computer via bluetooth as if the pi was a bluetooth keyboard. So, the latter if I understood you correctly.

Comment: Okay that I don't know how to do. You can get the raspberry pi zero to emulate a usb keyboard as you can find in the following link https://lifehacker.com/turn-a-raspberry-pi-zero-into-just-about-any-usb-device-1750112654 and you can access the raspberry pi zero via bluetooth by making a bluetooth accessible terminal which is explained in this link https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/02/headless-raspberry-pi-configuration-over-bluetooth/ but making it emulate a bluetooth keyboard I don't know how to do